# system is currently not set up to build kernel modules

Tags: 16.04, kernel, virtualbox

when I tried to run the following command

```
# /sbin/vboxconfig
```

I got the following

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

also I tried the following

```
# sudo apt install linux-headers-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic' has no installation candidate
```

my version is  16.04

how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Did you run `apt-get update`? You also might want to install with `apt-get install linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04-edge`.

Comment: @Thomas yes I ran `apt-get update`. I tried `apt-get install linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04-edge`  but I got  
`E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04-edge
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04-edge'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04-edge'`

Comment: I would suggest just trying `sudo apt install linux-headers-generic` first.

Comment: @guiverc this what I got `linux-headers-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0.135.141).`